# How to implement combobox in bootstrap and bind data from database?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, combobox, fuelux

I using bootstrap in my asp.net web form application.I need to implement combobox (User selects from drop down and can edit the text) in my UI but I don't see any combobox in bootstrap components.I found below two articles in which I can able to create the combo box but not sure how to bind the data from database in these two cases.

http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#combobox
https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox

Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: what is your data? what is your data format?

Comment: Why not a simple bootstrap select?

Comment: My data will be list of strings (returnee from SQL database) that should be displayed in a combobox.

Comment: Bootstrap select doesn't allow to edit the selected text. My requirement is user should able to select from a drop down. Once selected, user should able to edit the selected text.(Same as the functionality of combobox)

Answer (score 0):

Bootsrap does actually have a component that can give you the look you are going for, they are called buttons with dropdowns and can read more about them [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-dropdowns). Now how you populate the list items, edit them and save the value depends a lot on what type of database you are using.

I would put this in a comment but still don't have the reputation to use them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.